# How to make a CSS list of boxes which folds on window resize?

Tags: css, alignment

I'm not so good in CSS, so I don't even know where to start... but I need to quickly make a list of objects which would display 4 in a row (and as many rows as needed for objects) by default, however, when the window size is smaller, so that 4 objects don't fit in, they automatically re-arrange in 2 per row...

Does anybody have a link to the CSS code, which achieves that? I don't even know how it's called so I don't know what to search for...

Thanks!

[image]

**CSS**

```
#welcomemessage {
position: relative;
top: 5px;
left: 10px;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
max-width: 340px;
padding-left: 50px;
z-index: 1;

}

#maincontent {
position: relative;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
max-width: 700px;
padding-left: 50px;
z-index: 1;
}

.appbox {
position: relative;
background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
border-radius: 8px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id='welcomemessage'>
         Welcome to InfraNodus, <%= user.name %>. 
     Using this platform you can convert any text into network. 
    Try out our apps to see how it works.
     </div>

    <div id='maincontent'>
        &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
      <div class="appbox">Here we go</div>
      <div class="appbox">Here we go again</div>
      <div class="appbox">Here we go again</div>
      <div class="appbox">Here we go again</div>
      <div class="appbox">Here we go again</div>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```css
ul{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0 2% 10px 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  li{
    width: 47%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
  <li>This is a bloc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you know how to center the text inside the div vertically?

Comment: What do you mean ? The text is already centered vertically and horizontally